# Using external CSS and writing adding elements inside Google Earth Engine map window

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using GEE for displaying a shapefile. Is there any way I can add a logo that displays on the map area using external CSS? Can I use a CDN link for CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with external CSS. You can use a `ui.Label()` with an `imageUrl` to display images stored under `gstatic.com`. This is quite a big limitation of course, and might not work for your specific case.

In any case, here's an example that shows an SVG picked up from https://fonts.google.com/icons.

```
var logo = ui.Label({
  value: 'Some text shown on hover',
  imageUrl: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialiconsoutlined/sentiment_satisfied/v11/24px.svg'
})

Map.add(logo)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bae0437c0360101971343f73b7c6f744